# Working with Arabic in Python on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, arabic

I'm working on a project that has some data in Arabic. One task requires me to create a database mapping for some dicts. I don't read Arabic, but with the help of Google Translate and original English versions of the data, I'm able to surmise which Arabic strings map to the database columns.

The problem I'm facing is that Python / MacOS / Something seems to be converting ligatures (?) in the Arabic when I use copy/paste on them, which leads to my code not recognizing some of the dicts.

I believe I have a way around the problem, but given the nature of the work I'm doing, I would like to understand what is happening.

The original Arabic key looks like this:

[image: original]

However, when I copy/paste it on MacOS, it converts to the following:

[image]

Google Translate, MacOS, Safari, etc... all seem to think these are equivalent text, but Python disagrees and throws a KeyError when it encounters the original (due to the system having converted it to the second version. Even if I paste it here, it converts: الفئة

Is there a way to work with this text at the system level that does not end up with it being converted to something that Python doesn't recognize?

Comment: the original is wrong and considered a typo, the key that you get when you paste it is the correct word `(الفئة)`

Comment: @MoeA In this case, I need to retain the typo in order to map the 350k entries that I have to the database columns. Do you know how I could force MacOS to ignore that error?

Comment: This question seems to be about your OS's handling of copy and paste, rather than a programming question, which would be better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody finds this and runs into a similar problem...

What I needed to do was to parse through 350k structured Arabic records (though not all with the same schema), extract the key values, map them to English database column names, and then insert the original records into a table. Thinking laziness would work, I created a set of the unique keys, printed it to screen, then copy/pasted it into a text editor, converted it to a dict, and used the Arabic words as dict keys and the English column names as the values. Except, I did not notice that when I pasted the set of Arabic field names that the system "fixed" the Arabic misspellings, resulting in key names that were no longer recognized when parsing the records.

To fix the problem, instead of printing the Arabic column names (there were 32 of them) to the screen, I created a SQLite database and inserted them into a table that also included a blank "standardized" column. I then went into SQLite and updated the records to map the English to the Arabic. I then read the table back into Python and created a lookup dict that I used when parsing the full data payload. Inserting the Arabic into SQLite did not "correct" the misspellings for me, and hence, the records extracted from there served as an accurate lookup.

The lookup table ended up looking like this:

[image]

In spite of trying, I never figured out how to get MacOS to stop correcting the misspelled Arabic.